# Android studio try to update the application from target sdk 22 to 23 and above

Tags: android, android-studio, android-10.0

I try to update my application from target sdk 22 to 23 and above to match the android 10 and i get a white screen and don't see the permisssions list

In the gradle file I use

```
compileSdkVersion 29
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVesrion 22
```

I try to add `uses-permission-sdk-23` but i still get the white screen

Comment: what do you mean by "white screen"?

Comment: @fireb86 just a white screen without any layout or the permission list of the application